# Apache docker container RAM memory limit needed

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, apache2

If a single user is downloading a single file of 2 GB, my apache container (docker, in demo website) uses more than 1 GB RAM.

In production website I tried with 2 apache containers * 14 GB RAM limit, and it is still not enough.

How can I optimize this? Is there a simple way to prevent out of memory?

Comment: Are you implying that you’re Apache container has problems because it is actually running out of memory? Or do you *think* Apache is misbehaving because it uses all the memory it can. - If the latter: rather than actively minimizing memory usage ,  in Linux it is generally considered to be much more wasteful to have memory and NOT use it , which is why linux  will use memory not needed for more important tasks for disk caching and such.

Comment: Oh, thank you. There is no problem, everything works fine with downloading - no user reported issues. So, I understand I tried to solve a problem that is not a problem.